# Could I use javascripts window.print to print zpl to a zebra printer that is hooked up via usb?

Tags: javascript, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, kiosk-mode

After viewing this link https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers/kiosk.html it appears to me that you can accomplish this task. I just wanted to know if anybody else has tried this. This coupled with putting chrome into kiosk mode(https://mycartpos.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868343-Enable-kiosk-printing-print-automatically-for-Google-Chrome-on-Windows) seems like it could achieve self service printing. If I am going about this wrong and should just stick to trying to figure out how to send raw zpl to the printer, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the KR403 as the 203 does not support ZPL. Consider using Zebra's Browser print to route from JavaScript to the USB port via this application:
https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/browser-print.html

Comment: I was thinking the same, but didn't see the KR printers listed as compatible with Browser Print.

Comment: I just saw that as well.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use network mode ?

```
function print()
{
  var zpl = "YOUR ZPL TEXT"
  var ip_addr = "YOUR IP"
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var url = "http://"+ip_addr+"/pstprnt";
  var method = "POST";
  var async = true;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onload = function () {
    var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 200 for "200 OK"
    var data = request.responseText; // Returned data, e.g., an HTML document.
    output.innerHTML = "Status: " + status + "<br>" + data;
  }

  request.open(method, url, async);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", zpl.length);

  // Actually sends the request to the server.
  request.send(zpl);
}
```

Comment: Sure, a useful answer, but the asker is looking specifically for USB, not network mode. At least explain the difference between them, otherwise this answer doesn't really address the question.